# Java gives wrong time zone

Tags: java, android, timezone

Java gives wrong timezone as output on my Android device.

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault(); 
System.out.println(tz.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT));
```

Output:

```
EET
```

But it should be

```
EEST
```

It is EEST (GMT+03:00, Istanbul) in the Date&Time settings on the device.

Comment: Did you check the Android settings, is it on the right timezone?

Comment: And whats the question exactly? I mean, are you sure this is wrong? Why would this be wrong? Why are you expecting the EST output?

Comment: @Claudio I checked, it is in correct timezone.

Comment: @RobQuist Yes I am sure it is wrong. I expect EEST not EST.

Comment: How did you make sure that it should be EEST?

Comment: @RobQuist Android settings is EEST and phone's clock shows EEST time.

Comment: With the `false` given to `getDisplayName()`, one would expect `EET` for a device in `EEST` but not `EST` which is UTC-5.

Comment: @laalto I miswrote EET as EST and making first parameter true solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `getDisplayName()` is:

> daylightTime  true for daylight time, false for standard time.

Given `false`, you'll get `EET` (UTC+2) for a device in `EEST` (UTC+3).